# jQuery carousel dots on click always going to first item

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a carousel with basic jquery - I'm using the `.css()` rule to simply toggle opacity between each slide.

The way I want to do this is on click of each dot I want to check if the specific class exists and if it does hide all other items and show that one. So far I have:

```
$('.dot').click(function() {
  $('.review-module--reviews').children().css('opacity', 0);
    if ($('.dot').hasClass('dot1')) {
      $('.review-one').css('opacity', 1);
      $('.dot1').addClass('dot-active');
    } else if ($('.dot').hasClass('dot2')) {
      $('.review-two').css('opacity', 1);
      $('.dot2').addClass('dot-active');
    } else {
      $('.review-three').css('opacity', 1);
      $('.dot3').addClass('dot-active');
   }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="review-module">
  <div class="review-module--reviews">
    <div class="review-one">

    </div>
    <div class="review-two">

    </div>
    <div class="review-three">

    </div> 
  </div>
  <span class="slider-dots">
    <div class="dot dot1"></div>
    <div class="dot dot2"></div>
    <div class="dot dot3"></div>
  </span>
</div>
```

However when I click on dots 2 and 3, it always targets the dot1 slide in the DOM. The `'dot-active'` class gets added successfully to dot1 but on click of 2 and 3, that class does not get added.

I also tried explicity checking for a true value in the if statement like so:

`if ($('.dot').hasClass('dot1') === true)`

Is this the best way to do this? Or should I consider a different thought process?

Comment: Use $(this) as pointer to current/clicked element, add class, and remove the rest of classes accordingly....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in this code:

```
if ($('.dot').hasClass('dotX'))
```

What you're actually doing here is fetching the list of all `.dot` elements and checking if the first one has the `dotX` class. As you can imagine, this will always pick up the first `.dot` element, which has the `dot1` class.

What you probably mean to do is to check if the element that was *clicked on* has the `dotX` class, for which you need to check only that element.

Either do so by using the current scope of the click handler:

```
if ($(this).hasClass('dotX'))
```

or by checking the target of the click event:

```
$('.dot').click(function(e) {
  $('.review-module--reviews').children().css('opacity', 0);
    if ($(e.target).hasClass('dot1')) {
```

Comment: This was it I needed to check the target. I misunderstood how that worked, I thought that `hasClass();` within a function would return it's clicked class.

Comment: And if you've 10 dots?! you'll add conditions everytime i thought that this is the point of using `data-* attributes`..

Comment: Yeah, while this answers you question I think the `data-` approach is a better way to do it in general.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use **[`data-* attributes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes)** instead so give every `.dot` a `data-review` that refer to the related `review` div :

```
$('.review-module--reviews div').hide(); //Hide all the slides

$('.dot').click(function() {
    var review = $(this).data('review');

    $('.review-module--reviews div').hide(); //Hide all slides
    $('.slider-dots .dot').removeClass('dot-active');  //Remove 'dot-active' class from all the dots

    $(this).addClass('dot-active'); //Active the clicked dot
    $('.review-'+review).show(); //Show the related slide
});
```

Then on click just get the review using jQuery method `.data()` and show the div with related class.

Hope this helps.

```js
$('.review-module--reviews div').hide();

$('.dot').click(function() {
  var review = $(this).data('review');

  $('.review-module--reviews div').hide();
  $('.slider-dots .dot').removeClass('dot-active');

  $(this).addClass('dot-active');
  $('.review-'+review).show();
});
```

```css
.dot-active{
  color: green;
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="slider-dots">
  <div class="dot dot1" data-review="one">dot1</div>
  <div class="dot dot2" data-review="two">dot2</div>
  <div class="dot dot3" data-review="three">dot3</div>
</span>
<br>
<div class="review-module">
  <div class="review-module--reviews">
    <div class="review-one">
      Review-one
    </div>
    <div class="review-two">
      Review-two
    </div>
    <div class="review-three">
      Review-three
    </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In the past I've done `$(this).addClass('dot-active').siblings().removeClass('dot-active');` to change active states. Is there a performance gain/loss from using `.slider-dots` vs using `siblings()`?

Comment: IMO there's no difference between the both in the such cases.

Answer (score 0):

Try this may be it can help you -

JAVASCRIPT CODE-

```
$('.dot').click(function() {
  $('.review-module--reviews').children().css('opacity', 0);
  $('.dot').removeClass('dot-active');
    if ($(this).hasClass('dot1')) {
      $('.review-one').css('opacity', 1);
      $(this).addClass('dot-active');
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('dot2')) {
      $('.review-two').css('opacity', 1);
      $(this).addClass('dot-active');
    } else {
      $('.review-three').css('opacity', 1);
      $(this).addClass('dot-active');
   }
});
```